# Distribution of fragments in fission reactions

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics

What decides the mass and charge distribution of fission fragments? are these factors decided at or before the saddle point? and how? Why does the valley in the distribution function become shallow on increasing the excitation energy? Could anyone provide links to some mathematical details if possible?